# Zeroes of irreducible two variables polynomial which is reducible in algebraic closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field of characteristic $0$, $\bar{\mathbb{F}}$ its algebraic closure, $p(x,y) \in \mathbb{F}[x,y]$ an irreducible polynomial which is reducible in $\bar{\mathbb{F}}[x,y]$. Show that $p(x,y)$ has only a finite number of zeroes in $\mathbb{F}^2$.

The approach suggested involves demonstrating something like that: if $p(x,y)=f(x,y)g(x,y)$, $f, g \in \bar{\mathbb{F}}[x,y]$ and $(a,b) \in \mathbb{F}^2$ is a zero of $p(a,b)=0$, then $p(a,b)=f(a,b)=g(a,b)=0$. In other terms if $p$ has a zero in $\mathbb{F}^2$, then this is an intersection point of the curves $f=0$ and $g=0$. Let's take for example $p=x^2+y^2$, which is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$. Then $x^2+y^2=(x+iy)(x-iy)$ and the only real root of $p$ is (0,0) which is the intersection point of $(x+iy)$ and $(x-iy)$.

Any other approach to the problem is obviously welcomed. Anyway this problem is intended for undergraduates with a good knowledge of algebra and galois theory, so it shouldn't involve any heavy machinery such as heavy algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $p(x,y)$ is reducible in $\bar{\mathbb{F}}[x,y]$ and let  $g(x,y)\in \bar{\mathbb{F}}[x,y]$ be one of its irreducible factors.
Let $g=g_1,g_2,..., g_n (n\geq 2)$ be the conjugates of $g$ under the Galois group $G=\operatorname {Gal(\bar{\mathbb{F}}/\mathbb F)}$.
Since $g$ divides $p$, so do all the $g_i$'s: we have $$p=g_1\cdot g_2\cdot \ldots\cdot g_n\cdot \ldots\in \bar{\mathbb{F}}[x,y]$$
Now if $(a,b)\in \mathbb F^2$ is a zero of $g$, it will certainly be a zero of all the $g_i$'s.
In particular it will belong to the intersection $V(g_1)\cap V(g_2)\subset \bar{\mathbb{F}}^2$ of the curves $g_1=0$ and $g_2=0$.
But that intersection is finite, like all intersections of two different irreducible algebraic curves: [Fulton](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf)  1.6,Proposition 2, page 9.

**Conclusion**
The curve $p=0$ has indeed only finitely many zeros over $\mathbb F$.

**Edit**
Why does $g$ have only many conjugates?
Because each coefficient of  $g$ has only finitely many conjugates:
Indeed given an element $a\in \bar {\mathbb F}$, let $f(X)\in \mathbb F[X]$ be its minimal polynomial.
Every conjugate $\gamma(a)\in \bar{\mathbb F}\; (\gamma\in G=\operatorname {Gal(\bar{\mathbb{F}}/\mathbb F)})$ is a zero of $f(X)$ too, so that the number of such conjugates is finite, bounded by the degree of $f(X)$ .
(This might appear a bit surprising, since $G$ itself will be infinite in general.)

**New Edit**
The hypothesis "$\mathbb F$ has characteristic zero" ensures that the extension $\mathbb F\subset \bar{\mathbb F}$ is Galois.
As a consequence an element of $\bar F$ fixed by the Galois group $G=\operatorname {Gal(\bar{\mathbb{F}}/\mathbb F)}$ must belong to $\mathbb F$ and similarly for polynomials.
As a consequence when I wrote $p=g_1\cdot g_2\cdot \ldots\cdot g_n\cdot \ldots\in \bar{\mathbb{F}}[x,y]$, which was enough to conclude, we had actually $p=g_1\cdot g_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot g_n\in \bar{\mathbb{F}}[x,y]$ : the ellipsis "$\cdot \ldots$" is in fact non-existent.
Indeed the product $g_1\cdot g_2\cdot \ldots\cdot g_n$ is invariant under $G$ and thus has coefficients in $\mathbb F$ by what I just wrote.
Since it divides the irreducible polynomial $p \in \mathbb F[x,y]$, it must be equal to $p$.

Comment: Dear Georges, I'm deeply thankful for your insightful solution, which makes me more interested toward learning some basic algebraic geometry from an introductory text as Fulton's one. My thanks go also to @user26857 for his various observations and for the edit to my post. To both of you go my excuses for my late feedback: as I've explained to Georges in a mail we're having some troubles with Internet connection in my university which is ready to be solved, I hope. Anyway yesterday I found a solution to the problem, but I won't post it cause it's almost the same of Georges.